# how to generate auth 2.0 in karate I saw a sample in karate Demo project but in our case we need to send it as "Authorization Code"

Tags: karate

How to generate OAuth 2.0 token via karate.

How we have tried in Postman:

1. On Authorization tab select OAuth 2.0
2. Select Header Prefix Bearer
3. Grant-Type is "Authorization Code"
4. Callback URL is selected as when we will click submit it redirects to a browser where we have to enter credentials and a user is validated once it is validated the browser redirects back to Postman
5. Add "Auth URL" and "Access Token URL"
6. Enter "Client ID" and "Client Secret"
7. Select "Client Authentication" as Send as Basic Auth Header.

Postman then redirects to a browser where we enter username and password and once authenticated it redirects user back to postman with access token.

Question:
When we provide grant_type as "authorization code" in Karate we are getting an error as `{"error":"unsupported_grant_type","error_description":"Unsupported grant_type"}`. What to provide here as when we provide "password" we are getting 401 and when we provide "authorization code" we are getting 400.

Secondly, Can we automate such scenario where a browser is invoked as well and we have to enter credentials can we achieve it via Karate as then we have to store the token and pass in the APIs?

```
  Background:
    * url 'http://localhost:8080/pathdetails'

  Scenario: get all users and then get the first user by id
    * path 'token'
    * form field grant_type = 'authorization code'
    * form field client_id = 'ourapiclient'
    * form field client_secret = '324243324-3334-334-343-3432423424'
    * method post
    * status 200

    * def accessToken = response.access_token
```

EDITED**********

I have now tried to send a API request to Auth URL which redirects to the browser and returns HTML page.

```
    Given url 'http://localhost:8080/myurlpath/auth'
    * form field response_type = 'code'
    * form field client_id = 'abcc'
    * form field scope = 'openconnect'
    * form field redirect_uri = 'http://localhost:8080/redirecturlpath'
    * form field state = 'cEY3R-YfsoM9232diS72COdHTA8uPv9K49pjZaPag5M.8akinzwobn8.abcd4'
    * method get
    * status 200
    * print 'Response is........',response
```

This returned an HTML page which is exactly the same page I see when I send request from Postman. How to now enter username and password in karate on this html page as this page was returned as part of the response of above API.

I was expecting above will return me a code and after that I will call the request token endpoint but above redirected me to where I enter username and password and then once it is successful it redirects back to Postman and in URL I can see the code as well.

```
curl --request POST \
  --url 'https://YOUR_DOMAIN/oauth/token' \
  --header 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  --data grant_type=authorization_code \
  --data 'client_id=YOUR_CLIENT_ID' \
  --data client_secret=YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET \
  --data code=YOUR_AUTHORIZATION_CODE \
  --data 'redirect_uri=https://YOUR_APP/callback'
```

How to get the code which is needed by the token API?

I tried sending Auth API to access like below but no code or token got returned in the response.

```
Given driver 'http://localhost:8080/myurlpath/auth?scope=openconnect&state=cEY3R-YfsoM9232diS72COdHTA8uPv9K49pjZaPag5M.8akinzwobn8.abcd4&response_type=code&client_id=abcc&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Fauth%2Fmyurlpath'
* fullscreen()
And input('#username', 'username')
And input('#password', 'password')
When click('#login')
```

The above doesn't return any error but it doesn't return the code I am looking for as well

[image]

Comment: I'm going to pass on this one. hope the community helps you, in my opinion this should be possible without a browser, because ultimately everything is an HTTP request, you just need to look at the developer-tools "network" tab and do the same thing in a karate script. read the examples, all the best: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bkarate%5D+oauth

Comment: @PeterThomas To reach the second stage where it opens the browser I need to pass grant type as "authorization code". As when I select it as password API throws as error 401. From where I can see the list of all supported grant types?

Comment: no idea, sorry ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Maddy To see grant types You need access to auth0, or ask your devs to tell You what grants are implemented here you can read more:
https://auth0.com/docs/configure/applications/application-grant-types

And here You can read how to implement autorization-code flow:
https://auth0.com/docs/login/authentication/add-login-auth-code-flow

To make Your life easier You could ask devs to implement Password-realm-grant but this is not recommended.

Comment: Thanks for this. authorization_code grant type worked. But looking at above URL it shows first I have to authenticate and then need to call token URL. I tried send the request to authorization code URL first and it returned me the page where postman redirects us. In response I got an HTML page back. Now on that HTML page I need to enter user credentials. As per the documentation it should return me "Code" but in my case it returned me an HTML page which is what I was expecting. How to proceed from here and enter credentials. Updating my question with what I tried now

Comment: It will return "Code" when You log in. You should check if there is API call to log in user (i am not sure if this is possible) with authorization code grant on auth0 support forums.

As a workaround use Karate UI in headless mode to retrieve token,  navigate to this log in page and log in.


Here is an example how to handle login:
https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/blob/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/driver/demo/demo-01.feature


Or as I said in the answer implement Password grant:
https://auth0.com/docs/authorization/flows/call-your-api-using-resource-owner-password-flow

Comment: Awesome. thanks I tried the above way to send the request via karate UI in headless mode and it open browser where I enter username and password and click the button it then closes the browser and in logs I can see the redirect URL which contains the code. How I can retrieve that code?

Comment: If you got:

`HTTP/1.1 302 Found`

Then just extract code from url:
 `https://YOUR_APP/callback?code=AUTHORIZATION_CODE&state=xyzABC123`

Simple Javascript function should extract code from URL

Comment: It is not returning 302 in response there are many redirections and the URLs are inside "method":"Page.frameNavigated". So I am not sure how to do the first part of extracting the URL

Comment: DEBUG c.intuit.karate.driver.DriverOptions contains the URL which has code. Like in API automation we the values can be extracted from "response" what about in Karate UI?

Comment: Secondly, is there a callback URL in karate the way it is for Postman? I need that for the Authentication endpoint to pass the redirect URL to be of karate. Like we have https://oauth.pstmn.io/v1/callback in Postman

Comment: The callback comes from Auth. You can change browser to headfull and check network in browser or simply open network in your browser and log in to Your app. There will be one or two calls with status 302 one of them will be callback.  You have two options either filter everything You have as response to find that specific pageFrame or try to intercept requests.

You could also try to use `waitForUrl` after Inspecting the network in browser and find what request sends code.

Comment: Added the screenshot when I am trying to authenticate via POSTMAN. Postman opens the browser and after I enter username and password I can see 2 calls with 302 Found So it means one of this I need to give as redirect URL in authorization API in karate? I tried giving second one with 302 Found but the code returned in karate isn't working in token API. Token API in karate says "Invalid Code"

Comment: Added the screenshot. I think with your help I am very near the solution. There are two 302 calls and one callback the callback is of Postman so I can't give Postman callback in Karate. I talked to the developer and they asked me I should have a karate callback to provide where the code will be returned.

Comment: You dont need whole URL, only code= part of the url. This is autorization_code parameter that You have to pass in the request to get token.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how rectify one of oAuth 2.0 token generation

```
* def cid = 'client_id'
* def csec = 'token_secret'
* def AuthCode = Java.type('com.test.qa.aut.authCode')  
* print AuthCode.Code()  
* def authentication = 'Basic ' + AuthCode.Code(cid, csec)
* print authentication

* url 'https://acpint.online.com/default/np/oauth2/'
* header Authorization = authentication
And header Content-Type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'
* form field grant_type = 'client_credentials'
Then method post
And status 200
Then print response
```

Java class:

```java
package com.test.qa.aut;
import java.util.Base64;
public class authCode {
    public static String Code(String clientId, String clientSecret) {
        String auth = clientId + ":" + clientSecret;
        String authentication = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(auth.getBytes());
        return authentication;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution for creating access token OAuth 2.0 with PKCE

```
    Feature: OAuth 2.0 Authentication with Authorization Code grant type and PKCE

  Background:
    * url 'https://aaa.amazoncognito.com/oauth2'
    * def scope = 'openid profile'
    * def callbackURL = 'https://aaa.com'
    * def grantType = 'authorization_code'
    * configure ssl = true
    * def ac = Java.type('utilities.AuthCode')
    * def newClass = new ac()
    * def cV = newClass.generateCodeVerifier()
    #* print 'code verify= '+ cV
    * def cC = newClass.generateCodeChallenge(cV)
    #* print 'code chal= '+ cC
    * def sleep = function(millis){ java.lang.Thread.sleep(millis) }
    * def delay = 1000


  Scenario: Get Access Token with PKCE

    Given path 'authorize'
    * configure followRedirects = false
    * form field response_type = 'code'
    * form field client_id = clientID
    * form field client_secret = clientSecret
    * form field scope = 'openid profile'
    * form field redirect_uri = 'https://aaa.com'
    * form field code_challenge = cC
    * form field code_challenge_method = 'S256'
    * method get
    * status 302
    * def location = responseHeaders['Location'][0]

    #auth code
    * configure driver = { type: 'chrome', addOptions: ["--remote-allow-origins=*"] }
    Given driver location
    * sleep(delay)
    And input('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[1]/input', username)
    And input('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/form/div[2]/input', password)
    When click('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/form/input[3]')
    * def actualUrl = waitForUrl('?code')
    * def authCode = actualUrl.substring(actualUrl.lastIndexOf('=') + 1)
    * driver.quit()

    #final
    * configure followRedirects = true
    Given url 'https://aaa.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token'
    * header Content-Type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
    * form field grant_type = 'authorization_code'
    * form field client_id = clientID
    * form field client_secret = clientSecret
    * form field code_verifier = cV
    * form field code = authCode
    * form field redirect_uri = 'https://aaa.com'
    * method post
    * status 200
    * match response.token_type == 'Bearer'
    * def id_token = response.id_token
    * def access_token = response.access_token
    * def refresh_token = response.refresh_token
    #* print 'access token is = '+ access_token
```

For AuthCode java class is

```
    package utilities;

import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.util.Base64;

public class AuthCode {




    /**
     * This method generates a secure string used as the PKCE code verifier value.
     * In PKCE, you use the code verifier value:
     * 1. When you generate a code challenge value.
     * 2. When you exchange an authorization code for a bearer JWT token.
     * @return A random code verifier value.
     */
    final public String generateCodeVerifier() {

        SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
        byte[] bytes = new byte[36];
        secureRandom.nextBytes(bytes);

        String result = Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(bytes);
        //System.out.println("code verifier = " + result);
        return result;
    }


    /**
     * This method generates a code challenge value by SHA-256 and base64 encoding the code verifier value.
     * In PKCE, you use the code challenge value when you construct the authorization request uri.
     * @param codeVerifierValue A random string value.
     * @return An encoded code challenge string value.
     * @throws NoSuchAlgorithmException
     */
    public String generateCodeChallengeHash(String codeVerifierValue) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
        byte[] codeVerifierBytes = codeVerifierValue.getBytes(StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
        byte[] digest = messageDigest.digest(codeVerifierBytes);

        return Base64.getUrlEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(digest);
    }

   public String generateCodeChallenge(String cV){


      // System.out.println("code verifier in cC method = " + cV);
       String result;
       try {
           result = generateCodeChallengeHash(cV);
       } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
           throw new RuntimeException(e);
       }

      //System.out.println("generated Code Challenge = " + result);
       return result;
   }

}
```